# mp3's tagged with "Unknown Artist"

Tags: ubuntu-one, music, mp3, id3

I'm having the same problem as many others and its pretty frustrating. Whereby, mp3s are tagged as "Unknown Artist".

I'm in my second paid month of the U1 Streaming Service, and while its good, I still can't get past this "Unknown Artist" issue.  I've been using EasyTAG to "correct" the ID3 tags, but 9x out of 10, they are already correct. I re-upload the songs over and over again but its no use. What am I doing wrong?

I have have some albums where half the tracks are under "Unknown Artist" and the other half are reporting correctly - yet they all have the same tags?   It's very annoying.

I've put a fair amount of time in trying to source an answer or a solution that I can handle on my end, but I'm yet to find one. If you can help, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a link to your question while looking through my list of bugs. I'd like to let you know that the music scanning service has been completely revamped in the last couple weeks and we're giving special attention to new failures now.

Please give the service a try and let us know if you still experience problems.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue and, so far, the only workaround I have found, is to update some song's properties and load again the files to U1. 
Another way is to delete and upload the songs with the Web interface of U1.

Of course these are not valid solutions because:
1) with the web interface you can upload only a file at a time (impossible job with hundreds of them)
2) changing some song's properties and load again the files don't mean you will succeed. Sometimes it works, sometimes not.

I definitely believe that this is a bug that must be resolved.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I'm sure they would already know about this bug?  I'm wondering if I need to do anything more. I have tried deleting tracks from the web interface and reloading, I think on some occasions it did work. I haven't continued, because, yes, its far too time consuming.  I think I'll just need to do it for the songs I really want to listen too in the meantime...until U1 is fixed or there is another service I can switch too :(

Comment: It's always possible to make a search in Launchpad for bugs of this kind, and if none is found, to open a new one. This will help for sure to make U1 a better service.